# unable to send mail when using 3G, but working normally on WIFI

Tags: email

I am using Hmailserver as a mail server, and it is working normally for mail clients using a standard internet connection (wired or wireless).

But when using a mobile device in 3G mode, suddenly it is not possible to send emails anymore.   In the mail client there is a non saying error message (such as unknown error ocurred). Is there any reason for this?

Comment: in 3g mode are you able to recieve the mails???

Comment: yes, receiving emails was ok, the problem was only with sending on 3G. I discovered the reason, I have changed the port on the mail server to 569, and configured the clients to use that port as well, and then it works on 3G as well !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite hard to say; however, e-mail usually travels over port 25 when using [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol). Likely your 3G provider is blocking outgoing port 25 connections.

You can verify this by using telnet (a Google for "Windows telnet" will provide some Microsoft documentation) to connect to a well-known mail server (these are advertised in [DNS MX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) records). On Windows, I believe the syntax at the command line would be: "telnet <host> 25" (for Google a valid mail-host is alt2.aspmx.l.google.com).

If your provider is blocking port 25 traffic, you will see a connection denied message. Usually ISP's prefer you connect to their SMTP server -- so that they can prevent SPAM from emanating from their network.

Comment: indeed this was what was happening, when changing the mail server port to 569 in hmailserver, and changing the mobile client to that port as well, it started working when using 3G as well..